# Does changing suspension bushing require camber adjustment?

Tags: suspension, mitsubishi, alignment, bushing, camber

I have Mitsubishi Mirage 1999 or sometimes called Lancer in some countries. I have recently changed the the rear and front suspension and took the car for camber adjustment and alignment. I noticed that the mechanic had not changed the rear bushings so as I was driving I noticed that there's a squeaking sound from a worn bushing. At first I changed 1 bushing and then I noticed another squeaking sound from another bushing in the left rear side.

As shown in the picture below, this is first bushing that I changed and the squeaking noise became less:

[image: bushing1]

A few days later, I noticed there's a squeaking noise from the same side (rear left) and the sound comes from this bushing in the diagram below:

[image: bushing 2]

I'm planning to change it at home, but worried that I need to redo the camber adjustment. Do I need to do camber adjustment again if I change this part?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commonly, any time you make a change to your suspension, you should get the alignment done. This is because while two parts may be close, they're most likely not going to be *exactly* the same. Even a millimeter difference can cause the alignment to be off enough to make a difference. Sometimes you can get away with it, but realistically you should get the alignment done if for no other reason to make sure. Tires can get expensive and cost a lot more than an alignment.

If you know you're going to do multiple things and they aren't at the same time, you should consider getting an alignment from somewhere they will give you unlimited or multiple alignments over time. This way you can ensure your alignment is good but there will only be one charge for it.

Another thing to think about while you are changing out the bushings. When you put the new bushings in, only loosely tighten them. Then once the car is fully on the ground, tighten then fully. If you torque the bolts while there is no weight on the suspension, when the weight gets back on the suspension, the bushings will be twisted. When twisted during normal operation, the bushings will wear out a lot quicker.